# How to use file chunks based on characters instead of lines for grep?

Tags: bash, unix, grep

I am trying to parse log files of the form below:

```
---
metadata1=2
data1=2,data3=5
END
---
metadata2=1
metadata1=4
data9=2,data3=2, data0=4
END
```

Each section between the `---` and `END` is an entry. I want to select the entire entry that contains a field such as `data1`. I was able to solve it with the following command, but it is painfully slow.

```
pcregrep -M '(?s)[\-].*data1.*END' temp.txt
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What if you just grep data1?

Comment: edited to add metadata. `grep` only selects the line, but I want the whole entry.

Comment: Is there always 1 line above data1? If yes you can use grep with -B option

Comment: unfortunately not

Comment: How big is your data set ? can you quantify 'slow' - how long does it take to process the data, what is your target

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parsing this file with pcregrep might be challenging. The 'pcregrep' does not have the ability to break the files into logical records. The pattern that was specific will try to find matching records by combining multiple record together. Sometimes including unmatched records in the output.

For example, if the input is "--- data=a END --- data1=a END", then the above command will select both records, as it will form a match between the initial '---', and the trailing 'END'

For this kind of input, consider using AWK. It has the ability to read input with custom record separator (RS), which make it easy to convert the input into records, and apply the  pattern. If you prefer, you can use Perl or Python.

Using awk `RS` to create "records", possible to apply the pattern test on every record

```
awk -v RS='END\n' '/data1/ { print $0 }' < log1 
awk -v RS='END\n' '/data1/ { print NR, $0 }' < log1
```

The second command include the record number in the output, if useful.

While AWK is not as fast as pcregrep, in this case, it will not have trouble processing large input set.

Comment: Why should awk being _not as fast as pcregrep_?

Comment: In theory, for simple cases, grep (or pcregrep) will be faster the equivalent awk script - there is some (minor) overhead in processing the AWK command, splitting lines into tokens, etc. I agree that for any practical purpose, the difference is meaningless, unless the file is VERY large.

Comment: The regex evaluation in awk itself should be faster than pcregrep because it's using POSIX regexes (or "awk regexes"). But I see the point you are making about the extra overhead of splitting into fields. I would say that this extra overhead only counts when the regex itself is very simple, probably not even then. Would like to see some benchmarks. (If digging hard enough, there could be some existing benchmarks on the internet maybe)

Answer (score 1):

I would use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=ORS="END\n"}/\ydata1/' file
```

**Explanation:**

awk works based on input *records*. By default such a record is a line of input, but this behaviour can be changed by setting the *record separator* (and *output record separator* for the output).

By setting them to `END\n`, we can search whole records of your input.

The regular expression `/\ydata1/` searches those records for the presence of the the term `data1`, the `\y` matches a word boundary, to prevent from matching `metadata1`.